# Can i use "react-native-health" for the expo

Tags: react-native, expo, healthkit

I want to use "react-native-health" for the expo and the platform is IOS, and I want to install it on my iPhone is this possible with the expo?

Comment: You should explain more till anyone can help you

Answer (score 1):

With `expo-dev-client` you can use `react-native-health` and continue you to use an expo managed project.

Link: https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/

Once you install `react-native-health`, you won't be able to use Expo Go anymore since Expo Go will not be able to run `react-native-health`. In order to test your app you will have to create a custom dev build, as shown in the link above. Once you have done so, you'll be able to easily test and iterate your app just like you would have with Expo Go.